# Constraint solver in .net core

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core

Currently I'm working in vehicle route optimization problem using .net core.

Implemented tabu search algorithm with vehicle capacity as a hard condition. This way I can limit the vehicle capacity. But i have to add more conditions wrt future requirements like delivery window time, time taken between two visits etc.

Question here is how effectively we can add multiple constraints in algorithm flow. Because traditionally we use if..else / switch or some business rule engines.

Also I read optaplanner using AI constraints solver with drools. Any equivalent in .net core.

Any suggestions in .net core how to achieve this would be more helpful.

Answer (score 0):

IBM CPLEX: https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/icos/20.1.0?topic=cplex-cnet-examples

Look at this list on AMPL:
https://ampl.com/products/solvers/solvers-we-sell/